# Verifying the analayticity of two real functions.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

This question is question 1.1 for Markushevitch's "Theory of Functions".

I want to verify that the functions $\cosh x $ and $e^{\sin x}$ are analytic for all $x$ real.

Now, I want to use Theorem 1.1 which states that a function $f(x)$ defined in a nbhd of the point $x_0$ is analytic at $x_0$ iff:

1. $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable in a nbhd of $x_0$.
2. There exist positive numbers $\delta$ and $M$ such that for any $x\in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ the inequality:

$$|f^{(k)}(x)|\le Mk!/\delta^k$$
holds for any nonnegative integer $k$.

So basically I need to show explicitly that condition 2. is satisfied.

Do you happen to know how exactly?

I mean, for $\cosh x$ we know that the $k$-th order derivative is either $\sinh x$ or $\cosh x$, so its absolute value either way is less than $(e^x+e^{-x})/2$; but how to find $\delta$ and $M$?

Comment: Perhaps take $\delta =1$ and $M$ to be the maximum value of either $\cosh(x)$ in the interval $[x_0-\delta, x_0 + \delta]$.

Comment: Yes, it seems this will work.

Comment: Do you still need help with $e^{\sin(x)}$?

Comment: Yes, if I pick $\delta=1$ for the case of $e^{\sin x}$; I think I still need somehow to find a general formula for the $k$-th derivative of this function.

Comment: @Demophilus yes I need help on $e^{\sin x}$.

Comment: Have the book talked about holomorphic functions up unto this point. If so it's trivial to prove. However without that machinery your problem becomes rather hard.

Comment: @Martin I see there's theorem 1.2 which states: "A function $f(z)$ of a complex variable is analytic on a domain $G$ iff $f(z)$ is differentiable at every point $z_0\in G$; it seems this solves this question as in both functions have a first derivative on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok by your theorem 1.2 it's easy. First pick $x_0 \in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$. Now consider the complex function $f(z) = \exp(\sin(z))$ this is the composition of two holomorphic functions, and thus $f$ is holomorphic in some (complex) neighbourhood $B(x_0,\epsilon)$ (well it's actually entire so the neighbourhood is $\mathbb C$). Hence $f$ is analytic there. Therefore it's also analytic on the restricted neighbourhood $]x_0-\epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon[$. Since this holds for all $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ you're done.